# Proper way to structure a Sync Framework DAL

Tags: .net, sql, wpf, linq, microsoft-sync-framework

I am creating a WPF app that needs to allow users to work in a temporary disconnected state and I plan to use a Local Database Cache.

My question's are about my data access layer.

- Do you typically create the whole DAL
  to point at the Cache or both and
  create a switching mechanism?
- Is Entity's a good way to go for my
  DAL against the Cache?
- I am used to L2S but my understanding
  is that I can't use that against
  SQLCE, correct?

Thanks!

PS:  Any good resources out there for using Sync, Linq, and WPF **ALL TOGETHER**?  Tutorials, videos, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992.aspx) or at least some of the [resources and examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx).

Comment: @Bryan Anderson: Thank you for taking the time to post.  I should have been more clear though.  What I am hoping for, in terms of resources, is putting them all together.  At the least, Sync Framework and LINQ.  Thoughts there?

Comment: I haven't gotten a chance to dive in to the sync framework yet. I'd probably pretend the sync framework isn't there when developing my app and just run everything against the cache. Then I'd have the sync framework update the cache and have that push changes to my app somehow. It's too bad they haven't released the source for their Mix10 planner yet. I'd keep an eye out for that since they seemed to have a good and reusable system in it.

Comment: Thanks! I Take it Mix10 had a nice Sync Framework app?  I'll have to keep my eye out.

Comment: It was called the Mix10 session planner. I was really impressed with how well it worked even when I was hopping on and offline constantly throughout Mix. Here's the Sync team's blog post about it http://blogs.msdn.com/sync/archive/2010/03/01/organize-yourself-at-mix10-using-mix10-session-planner-beta.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at this blog post:
http://blogs.msdn.com/matt/archive/2008/09/09/sql-ce-3-5-with-linq-to-sql.aspx

Comment: Interesting, thank you.  I had thought I would have to go a different route so this gives me options.